# Navigating prototype chain to Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out how a constructor function's prototype object looks like. Thus I tried the below.

Any idea why both lines show an empty object? Should not the bottom line print the `Object`'s prototype object (`Object.prototype`)?

```
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
console.log('Product prototype: ' + JSON.stringify(Product.prototype, null, 4));
console.log('Object prototype: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.getPrototypeOf(Product.prototype), null, 4));
```

Thank you.

Comment: A constructor function's prototype is itself. And, the Global object is not part of JavaScript, it's part of the host environment. JavaScript objects do not inherit from Global. They inherit from `Object`.

Comment: Sorry, with global object I meant `Object`. Corrected it.

Comment: They both print an empty object because the properties defined on the prototype are by definition not enumerable, and JSON.stringify only consumes enumerable properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` trys to convert javascript objects into JSON format.

You can't convert the Javascript functions, constructor info etc into JSON using `JSON.stringify`, which is why an empty object is returned;

Try this:

```
console.log('Product prototype: ' , Product.prototype);
console.log('Object prototype: ' , Object.getPrototypeOf(Product.prototype));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `JSON.stringify` works when i try to print out object literals I have defined. E.g. `console.log('MyRandomObj: ' + JSON.stringify(randomObj, null, 4));`.

If I try without stringify, I just get `[object Object]`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: as @Hamms more elegantly put it in their comment, you can't use stringify on the non-enumerable constructor info. This would cause havok as they're cyclic objects. And every object you printed would be spammed with the prototype sub-object, __proto, etc...

Comment: @Magnus when you use the `+` operator, it generically converts the object to a string `[Object object]` If you use a comma (call console.log with 2 arguments) it will nicely print the string along with the formatted object, which you can even play around with / inspect with more detail and ease.

Comment: Ah, amazing, I actually did not know that about the `+` operator. Thank you.